# Check if linear programming prob. legit

Tags: matlab

I have linear programming problems in the sense of 
http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/optim/ug/linprog.html
and also want to use linprog to solve them. I am just wondering if it is possible to precheck, if a lp is legit or not.

For example, if we had an inequality like 
    12x_1 + 3x_2 <= 40
and restrictions x_1 >= 3, x_2 >= 2 then the equality can not be fullfilled and the lp is not legit.

Is there a fast precoded way to do this, or do I need to code that myself?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can't you just feed the problem to `linprog` and check the `exitflag` to see if the problem was not feasible? I would assume the `linprog` checks before trying to solve it...

Comment: hi, yeah, maybe thats the best solution. I tried to look at the source code of linprog and the bounds are somewhat checked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to precheck whether LPs are solvable you can probably run linprog and play with the options a bit, for example make it do only 1 iteration.
This will sooner give you an idea of which can be solved, but of course if your goal is to reduce total computation time this will have an averse effect.